# Json file error out of START_ARRAY token caused by these [ ] brackets

Tags: java

I need method to get json from website and return offers witch `minSalary>1500&&marker_icon.equals("kotlin")`.I have tried this so far:

```
public void getRightOffers() { 
    ResponseEntity<JobObject> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
    });
    ResponseEntity<Salary> exchangeForSalary = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
    });
    Salary body1 = exchangeForSalary.getBody();
    int minSalary = body1.from;
    JobObject body = exchange.getBody();
    String marker_icon = body.marker_icon.toLowerCase();
    if (minSalary > 10000 &&marker_icon.equals("java")) {
        //it should return these offers
    }
}
```

But I got error: RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class packageOne.JobObject] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `packageOne.JobObject` out of START_ARRAY token;

My json starts with `[{"title...` and ends with `...false}]`. These [ ] couses the problem but I can't remove them from  json.

Also I have `JobObject,Salary and Skill` classes

Comment: Are you returning multiple `jobjects` and `salaries` in this array? Or an array with a **single** `jobject` and `salary`

Comment: I see already corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[...]` means the JSON response is an **array**.

You have to define your Java `ResponseEntity` to a compatible type like `List`:

```java
ResponseEntity<List<JobObject>> exchanges = ...
```

Comment: @Mannualky if this helped you you can approve the answer. As for your other question, please open another question.